# Docker not switching to Linux containers on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am running docker for windows on Windows 10 Enterprise edition.
It runs successfully in windows container mode.
When I do right-click on docker icon and "Switch to Linux Container", it keeps on switching and after some time, it throws the below error:

```
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line 36
at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.b__0() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 275
at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59
```

I am using hyper-v and it is enabled.
This issue is always reproducible. I have tried "restoring to factory default" and restart both but it does not solve my issue.
Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: In my experience, this looks like an intermittent error, after updating to latest docker in Window 10 Pro, this problem happens but after restart the docker engine, I can switch to Linux container.

Answer (score 1):

After updating to latest docker, my issue was also resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- Open Windows Subsytem for Linux (WSL) either by triggering your Linux distro from the Start menu or typing `wsl` from a PS/CMD prompt
- If you get error ffffffff then likely something is blocking port 53

How I solved it locally:

- do not reboot when Docker for Windows is in windows mode
- if you do, then switch it off after you reboot, start WSL, then switch it back on

Answer (score 0):

steps that helped me out:
1 - close your docker desktop
2 - type wsl (to start wsl manuallly) in cmd, you should not get any error
3 - start your docker desktop again,
4 - now switch to linux container

Answer (score 0):

To get docker 'Linux Container' to run on Win10 I needed to update WSL. Get the latest wsl version.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

1. Run in cmd: wsl -update
2. Restart computer